# Creating a windows kernel dump using C (kernel mode driver)

Tags: windows, dump, wdm

I need to create full memory and kernel memory dumps using a kernel mode driver in windows.

Just like what [.dump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562428(v=vs.85).aspx) command do using WinDBG, but I need to do it in my code.

Any Ideas how to do so?

Comment: [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx). Absolutely must be called out of context, unless you are fine with deadlocking your process.

Comment: @IInspectable: I believe that produces a user-mode (i.e., single process) dump rather than a kernel memory dump?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: True, I missed that the OP was asking for a kernel dump. `MiniDumpWriteDump` is indeed strictly a user-mode API, that will not dump kernel memory, threads, modules or kernel stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no good way to do that. You might just generate a BSOD through [KeBugCheck()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551948(v=vs.85).aspx) on a properly configured system. It relies on an undocumented [IoWriteCrashDump()](http://gate.upm.ro/os/LABs/Windows_OS_Internals_Curriculum_Resource_Kit-ACADEMIC/WindowsResearchKernel-WRK/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/bugcheck.c) method that you might want to investigate as well.